# How to include an image in a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm developing a web application using `Hibernate`, `Spring` and `JSP`.

In my `jsp` page I included images as the following :

```
<img src="img/logo/logo.png" alt="">
```

but they are not displayed when I run my `jsp` page.

The `jsp` page is located in :

```
WEB-INF/index.php
```

this `jsp` page calls three other pages in the same folder as the following :

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
    <%@ include file="sidebar.jsp" %>
    <%@ include file="main.jsp" %>
```

and images are located in :

```
WEB-INF/img
```

**How can I solve this problem ?**

Comment: what u mean by jsp is included in WEB-INF/`index.php`???

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that the image not display because of some path problem so that provide full context path and try it will work for you

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/img/logo/logo.png" alt="">
```

Try this one it maybe help you

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
<img src="../img/logo/logo.png" alt="">
```